# "Attempting to allocate already allocated variable " in Fortran code called from C++

Tags: c++, fortran

I am calling fortran subroutines from c++ by linking the fortran library to my c++ code. However after succesfull compilation with linking I run the program and receive the following error:

```
 Fortran runtime error: Attempting to allocate already allocated variable 'variableName'
```

In fortran file this looks like :

```
allocate(variableName(ns),variableName2(nr))    
variableName   = [(j,j=1,ns)]
variableName2 = [(j,j=1,nr)]
```

And then in my rather big c++ library I indeed have a variable called "variableName" and then this one is also on the fortran side. Is there any other way to get around this than grep the fortran library source and change the names of particular variables?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will save you having to change the code but you can set the name in fortran's iso_c_bindings with `BIND(C, NAME='variableName_F') :: variableName`

Comment: @EdSmith: That looks like an answer.

Comment: This does not look like an answer. And very likely the bug is in the Fortran part in a place which you don't show. Maybe the subroutine cannot be called two times or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the problem was that the c++ part tried to call fortran routine several times (not necessary at all) and then fortran side could not handle this.

However now this is solved.